# See if directory rec is used as symlink in Linux

Tags: linux, symlink

I want to see, if a symlink points to a directories in a specific dir - recursively.
Of course, I clould use

```
find / -type l -ls 2>/dev/null |grep /targetpath
```

But I do not want type all the (recurse) paths.

So I put all symlinks on my system into a file once.

```
find / -type l -ls 2>/dev/null >~/symlinks.txt
```

Then I list the directories recursively.

```
find /targetpath to start/ -maxdepth 2 -type d
```

And that is my question:
Can I pipe these paths from the last command to grep?
Grep should look into my file symlinks.txt and show the linecontent of matching lines (could be more symlinks pointing to this DIR)

I tried something like

```
find /targetpath to stat/ -maxdepth 2 -type d | xargs -0 -ifoo grep foo symlinks.txt
```

But it does not do, what I expect.

Or maybe an other, better solution?

Answer (score 0):

From [man find](https://linux.die.net/man/1/find):

> -lname pattern
>               File is a symbolic link whose contents match shell pattern  pattern. [...]

Try:

```
find / -lname '*/targetpath/*'
```

See [find-all-symlinks-to-a-directory-and-change-target-to-another-directory](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/150952/find-all-symlinks-to-a-directory-and-change-target-to-another-directory).

Comment: Sorry, I'm not so familiar with this topic.
But your solution shows all symlinks with /targetpath/ inside

What I need is :
Show ALL symlinks pointing to a physical dir - BUT-
I want investigate not only one dir.
I want have all symlinks pointing to all dirs in on dirtree - e.g. depth 3

So with other words,
where are all subdirs of one startingdir symlinked.

Comment: I don't get it then. Can you create an example directory&symlink structure? You want to follow symlinks? Just add `-L` to find.